# LocalBitCoins - Display Price - PHP

Tags: php

I would really appreciate help.

I need to take the Local Bitcoins ticker, and extract the GBP / avg_1hr price - and display it on a web page using PHP.

> https://localbitcoins.com/bitcoinaverage/ticker-all-currencies/

In the past I got something to work with the MtGox ticker using the following, but I can't seem to get this to work using the LocalBitcoins ticker.

```
<?php

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type:         application/json'));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCGBP/money/ticker');

$data = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

$obj = json_decode($data);

echo print_r($obj->{'data'}->{'avg'}->{'display_short'}."\n", true);

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at the JSON structure at all? You're not going to get it working with arbitrary property names.

Comment: Sorry to ask a stupid question, but which are the property names? I have tried changing parts, but I'm a bit of a noob so don't really know exactly what I need to change.

Comment: @ColinMcDermott the property names are what comes before the `:`, now try looking at that response, and see if you can understand what is the property name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json data is not in the structure you're trying to use. Try this:

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['GBP']['avg_1h'];
```

To see it in its entirety [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) the decoded data, like `var_dump(json_decode($json, true))`. *(Omit the `true` argument if you don't want objects to be converted to arrays.)*

Also, clearly, you need to change the `CURLOPT_URL` from mtgox to localbitcoins.

Comment: Thankyou! I have something working... amazing, cheers! You have saved me dozens of hours of staring at the screen scratching my head. Have a great weekend.